# RIA Services: Entities with child entities

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

Is it possible to have child objects on RIA Services entities that are also entities themselves?

```
public class Project
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Editable(false)]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public Machine Machine { get; set; }
}

public class Machine
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Editable(false)]
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I don't think so](http://www.riaservicesblog.net/Blog/post/Interlude-e28093-Entities-do-not-have-children.aspx), at least not in the traditional sense.

Comment: Colin's blog is an excellent source on RIA Services, but that particular post he is being a bit literal IMO. The notion of parent/child that most people expect is supported in RIA Services.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the `[Include]` attribute on the `Machine`property in the metadata class and add a call to `Include("Machine")` on the object context query.

See: http://vincenthomedev.wordpress.com/2010/01/08/using-wcf-ria-services-to-include-multi-table-master-detail-data/

Comment: I'm not using the entity framework.  I'm using Linq to SQL and POCO/DTO's.